# How to detect Adobe Illustrator files in Tika version 2.6?

Tags: java, apache-tika, adobe-illustrator

I want to use Tika 2.6 to detect files with the MIME type 'application/illustrator'. When I use the following code snippet, I always get the MIME type 'application/pdf':

```java
public MediaType detectMimeTypeFromContent(@NonNull File file) throws IOException {
    TikaConfig config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
    Detector detector = config.getDetector();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    TikaInputStream tikaStream = TikaInputStream.get(file, metadata);
    MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(tikaStream, metadata);
    tikaStream.close();

    return mediaType;
}
```

I use this dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-core:2.6.0'
implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:2.6.0'
```

How can I detect Adobe Illustrator files correctly?

Comment: I've been playing a bit with various export settings in Adobe Illustrator 2021. In these settings it is possible to on/off a setting called "create pdf compatible file" (or something like that). But no matter which setting you choose here, it will always insert a PDF into the AI file. If the setting is disabled, it is a kind of dummy PDF with the hint that it is not a compatible PDF document. So the magic byte is always %PDF. Tika always recognizes a PDF file. Does anyone perhaps have an idea what else could be done here to enable Tika to recognize the "correct" mime-type?

Comment: We have an open issue for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2689. We could add the logic at parse time, but we can't do it at detection time without parsing the whole file :(  Please chime in on our JIRA issue if you're willing to get that info at parse time.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe documentation shows they internally use 3 application/type settings

> List of document mime-types that are considered to be PDF or Illustrator documents.

- PDF
- Postscript
- Illustrator

also go one to say

> Adobe Illustrator’s file format is a variant of PDF. The main differences, in the context of Experience Manager Assets, is the following:

> Adobe Illustrator documents consist of a single page with multiple layers. Each layer is extracted as a PNG subasset under the main Illustrator asset.

> PDF documents consist of one or more pages. Each page is extracted as a single page PDF subasset under the main multi-page PDF document.

So Adobe applications have an inhouse typeset to distinguish application/illustrator, however, that is not a registered mimetype (AI is a subset of PDF as above )

Other applications may struggle with hybrids that are wrappers of one around the other so as one example
Linguist reports a content-type of application/postscript for *.ai whilst other report application/PDF  which may be due to
"Early versions [over 24 years ago] of the AI file format [Illustrator versions 3 through to 8 saved artwork as specialised EPS files,] are true EPS files with a restricted, compact syntax, with additional semantics represented by Illustrator-specific DSC comments that conform to DSC's Open Structuring Conventions."

Confused ? Dont be, simply **[like the current mime type register](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)**, accept AI files that are PDF like are application/pdf.

I often refer to text/pdf as the legacy format for ansi/pdf but those are not listed either

If a file starts with 40 bit signature `%PDF-` then irrespective of version or content

The RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8118.html

> PDF Versions
> The PDF format has gone through several revisions, primarily for the
> addition of features.  PDF features have generally been added in a
> way that older viewers "fail gracefully", because they can just
> ignore features they do not recognize.  Even so, the older the PDF
> version produced, the more legacy viewers will support that version,
> but the fewer features will be enabled.  **The "application/pdf" media
> type is used for all versions.***  See [ISOPDF2] Annex I, "PDF Versions
> and Compatibility".